# Set environment in current cmd using batch script

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I did search for an answer before posting this question but I couldn't find anything.

The problem is, I have a CMD shell from which different applications are being launched. What I want is to execute a bat files which can modify the current cmd environment.

In our current setup, we are using *call* to launch the batch file but that environment doesn't get updated in the callers cmd environment. Is there a command which runs the Batch in the current cmd shell?

Comment: Normally a batch file that's executed from a command prompt runs in the current instance of cmd.exe, with or without `call`. Is `start` used? Is a pipe used? Either of those can make the batch execute in a new instance of cmd.exe.

Comment: Is `setlocal` statement used in the batch script?

Comment: No start or Pipe or setLocal is not used. The batch file has simple set and setx. When the batch file is executed from the command prompt it opens a new instance and run the bat. So the env changes does not get set on the main cmd.

Comment: By "opens a new instance", do you mean it's not only running a new instance of cmd.exe but also opening a new console window?

Comment: FYI, setx.exe doesn't modify the current environment (it would be extremely bad practice for a child process to open and modify its parent process). Instead, it updates the registry and broadcasts a [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725497) message that makes Explorer reload its environment from the registry. The modified environment is only visible in instances of cmd.exe that are subsequently started from Explorer. You need to use the built-in `set` command to modify the environment of the current cmd shell.

Comment: Yes, a new console window launches and closes as soon as the batch finishes. I think that is cause I am using *call* to execute the bat file

Comment: Agreed, Setx is really bad practice. I am dealing with legacy code and I have been asked not to change it for now.

Comment: `call` doesn't cause a new instance of cmd.exe to run. Opening a new console would require `start` or inline vbscript tricks.

Comment: yes your right, my bad I totally forgot about the VBS script.

Answer (score 2):

**"The batch file has simple set and setx. When the batch file is executed from the command prompt it opens a new instance and run the bat. So the env changes does not get set on the main cmd."**

Both `set` and `setx` do not take effect in the command prompt that runs the batch file.

- `set` applies to the current command prompt only (this is the **new** command prompt belonging to the batch file **not** the one that runs the batch file). These changes are lost when the batch file terminates.
- `setx` only affects **new** command prompts (not those that are already open like the one that is used to run the batch file. You will only see thse changes if you start a **completely new** command prompt.

What you need to do is have a **single** batch file that uses `set` and **also** launches your applications.

You could start with something like [How to Use a Batch File to Create a Command Prompt Menu to Execute Commands](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/78083-batch-files-create-menu-execute-commands.html) and add the appropriate `set` commands just before you call each application.

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO PRESS 1, 2 OR 3 to select your task, or 4 to EXIT.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Open Notepad
ECHO 2 - Open Calculator
ECHO 3 - Open Notepad AND Calculator
ECHO 4 - EXIT
ECHO.
SET /P M=Type 1, 2, 3, or 4 then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO NOTE
IF %M%==2 GOTO CALC
IF %M%==3 GOTO BOTH
IF %M%==4 GOTO EOF
:NOTE
cd %windir%\system32\notepad.exe
start notepad.exe
GOTO MENU
:CALC
cd %windir%\system32\calc.exe
start calc.exe
GOTO MENU
:BOTH
cd %windir%\system32\notepad.exe
start notepad.exe
cd %windir%\system32\calc.exe
start calc.exe
GOTO MENU
```

---

Source [Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

> **Permanent changes**
>
> Changes made using the SET command are NOT permanent, they apply to
>   the current CMD prompt only and remain only until the CMD window is
>   closed. To permanently change a variable at the command line use SetX
>   or with the GUI - Control Panel | System | Environment | System/User
>   Variables
>
> Changing a variable permanently with SetX will not affect any CMD
>   prompt that is already open. Only new CMD prompts will get the new
>   setting.